# Can't create a table in SQLite, date variable error

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, date

i'm having problems to create a table in particular, this is my table

```
Create table EmpleadosCursos(Empleado constraint fk1_empleadoscursos references empleados,Curso constraint fk2_empleadoscursos references cursos,constraint pk_empleadoscursos primary key(empleado,curso),fecha date);
```

But it returns this error "Error: near "fecha": syntax error"
I can't find why, I tried with datetime too, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to have a name for your third column, something like below. :)

```
CREATE TABLE EmpleadosCursos(
    Empleado constraint fk1_empleadoscursos references empleados,
    Curso constraint fk2_empleadoscursos references cursos,
    COLUMN_NAME constraint pk_empleadoscursos primary key(empleado,curso),
    Fecha date
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no date/time field type in SQLite. As [described](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

> Each value stored in an SQLite database (or manipulated by the
>   database engine) has one of the following storage classes:
>
> NULL. The value is a NULL value.
>
> INTEGER. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.
>
> REAL. The value is a floating point value, stored as an 8-byte IEEE floating point number.
>
> TEXT. The value is a text string, stored using the database encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE).
>
> BLOB. The value is a blob of data, stored exactly as it was input.

Either store `Fecha` as a text *'2016-04-12 12:00:00'* or numeric equivalent value, *1460419200* (epoch UTC format or seconds since 1970-01-01). And practically any general purpose language (Java, C#, Perl, Python, PHP) can convert prior to import or update.